# HERE maps JS, disable mouse zoom but not panning

Tags: javascript, here-api

I would like the user to be able to pan the map with their mouse/finger. However I want to restrict zooming to only using HERE ui controls.

I have tried the following:

```
    // Since our marker is in the center of the map we need to make sure zooming occurs at center of map only
    // The user can zoom to their mouse position which may not be center, so we need to disable and allow zooming
    // via the +/- buttons only :(

    this.mapBehavior.disable(window.H.mapevents.Behavior.WHEELZOOM)
    this.mapBehavior.disable(window.H.mapevents.Behavior.PINCH_ZOOM)
    this.mapBehavior.disable(window.H.mapevents.Behavior.DBL_TAP_ZOOM)
    this.mapBehavior.enable(window.H.mapevents.Behavior.PANNING) <-- this renables zoom
```

Unfortunately if I disable WHEELZOOM, I also lose the ability to pan. 
If I re-enable PANNING, zooming is turned back on.

**How do I disable zooming without disabling panning?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following (mind the last line):

```js
this.mapBehavior.disable(window.H.mapevents.Behavior.WHEELZOOM)
this.mapBehavior.disable(window.H.mapevents.Behavior.PINCH_ZOOM)
this.mapBehavior.disable(window.H.mapevents.Behavior.DBL_TAP_ZOOM)
this.mapBehavior.enable(window.H.mapevents.Behavior.DRAGGING)
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem why dragging was disabled was that you try to disable the feature which doesn't exist in Behavior object (`PINCH_ZOOM` & `DBL_TAP_ZOOM`). Also the way how features should be disabled is different in API version 3.0 and API version 3.1 (latest). From the code above I see that you use older version 3.0, therefore:

**In version 3.0 there are only 3 features you can disable/enable:**
`H.mapevents.Behavior.DBLTAPZOOM`,`H.mapevents.Behavior.DRAGGING`, `H.mapevents.Behavior.WHEELZOOM`

So your code to disable zooming should look like:

```js
this.mapBehavior.disable(window.H.mapevents.Behavior.WHEELZOOM)
this.mapBehavior.disable(window.H.mapevents.Behavior.DBLTAPZOOM)
```

**In version 3.1 there are more features you can disable/enable:**
`H.mapevents.Behavior.Feature.PANNING`, `H.mapevents.Behavior.Feature.PINCH_ZOOM`, `H.mapevents.Behavior.Feature.WHEEL_ZOOM`, `H.mapevents.Behavior.Feature.DBL_TAP_ZOOM`, `H.mapevents.Behavior.Feature.FRACTIONAL_ZOOM`, `H.mapevents.Behavior.Feature.HEADING`, `H.mapevents.Behavior.Feature.TILT`,

So your code to disable zooming would (if you used version 3.1) look like:

```js
this.mapBehavior.disable(window.H.mapevents.Behavior.Feature.WHEEL_ZOOM)
this.mapBehavior.disable(window.H.mapevents.Behavior.Feature.PINCH_ZOOM)
this.mapBehavior.disable(window.H.mapevents.Behavior.Feature.DBL_TAP_ZOOM)
```

See simple [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lkym89ef/1/) example to disable zoom with API version 3.1.

Comment: This did not work for me, Feature is undefined. I believe I must be running an older version of HERE maps. Thank you though

Comment: I see you use older version of HERE maps API. I updated my answer to cover solutions for both versions (older 3.0 as well as latest 3.1) of API.